# How to delete network interface of MAC using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, networking, interface, system.configuration

I am working on MAC Application in which i have to create VPN Connection through my application.

I am able to create VPN connection successfully but now I want to delete the interface which was created by my application in network of System Preference.

I tried below code it run successfully but it does not delete that from network list

```
service = SCNetworkServiceCopy(prefs, (__bridge CFStringRef)(config.serviceID));
Boolean isDeleted = SCNetworkServiceRemove(service);
```

Is there any other methods to delete the network interface?

Comment: so "`isDeleted`" returns true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below method delete the interface but we need to save changes what ever we made.

```
SCNetworkServiceCopy(prefs, (__bridge CFStringRef)(config.serviceID));
```

To save setting we need to call the below method to Save changes we made in network.

```
SCPreferencesApplyChanges(prefs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* serviceIDa = @"FB6AD34D-DF8B-4FEC-B715-6F76EA5E5D83";
SCNetworkServiceRef serviceDelete = SCNetworkServiceCopy(prefs, (__bridge CFStringRef)(serviceIDa));

BOOL commit = 0;
SCPreferencesLock(prefs, TRUE);
SCNetworkServiceCopy(prefs, (__bridge CFStringRef) (serviceIDa));
SCNetworkSetRef networkSetAll = SCNetworkSetCopyCurrent(prefs);
if(SCNetworkSetRemoveService(networkSetAll,serviceDelete)){
    NSLog(@"Remove services ");
    commit = 1;
}
```

//Now for Commit changes

```
 SCPreferencesUnlock(prefs);
if (commit) {
    SCPreferencesCommitChanges(prefs);
    SCPreferencesApplyChanges(prefs);
}
CFRelease(networkSetAll);
```